# Is the verb “flicker” used correctly?

Tags: vocabulary

Is the verb “flicker” used correctly? I mean I've seen the word flicker for light, and for finger, but is it used for the whole body?

> "Ryan uneasily flickered in his seat"

Comment: Hi, I think the question might be closed because the usage of the word 'flicker' can be checked in an online dictionary, and I think there are examples provided. Why not compare your sentence with one of those examples to check if you used it correctly. Kindly post what is unclear to you here. :) All the best!

Answer (score 4):

Flicker is used for small body parts like eyelids, but not normally for an entire body.  In this sentence, it sounds to me like Ryan is a holographic projection.

The word I would use is 'fidget'.

> "Ryan uneasily fidgeted in his seat."

Comment: Things that flicker generate or allow/block light.  Candles, lamps, torches, lightning can be said to flicker.  When something that isn't a light is said to flicker, you are saying it's flashing in and out of sight quickly like a rapidly blinking light.